# ¿como setear los atributo de algo por teclado dentro de una pequeña interfaz?

Tags: java

Os cuento mi problema. Tengo que hacer una colección de cartas de rol cada carta tiene unos atributos y tengo una clase mazo con un array de cartas.
En el main tengo que crear una pequeña interfaz para pedir los diferente métodos mi problema es que no se como pedir por teclado los elementos de las cartas una vez creadas. Os pongo el código para que se vea.
Se que los que tengo puesto con get están mal, pero la ponerlos con set me da un error y no se solucionarlo. Gracias por la ayuda

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File miFichero = new File("Coleccion.dat");
    Mazo m = null;
    if (!miFichero.exists()) {
        m = new Mazo();
        System.out.println(m.toString());
    } else {
        // m = deserializa();
    }

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("1. Añadir una nueva carta");
        System.out.println("2. Buscar carta por su nombre");
        System.out.println("3. Eliminar una carta");
        System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas");
        System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas nuevas");
        System.out.println("5. Listar  todas las cartas segunda mano");
        System.out.println("6. Buscar la carta mas cara");
        System.out.println("7. Buscar la carta mas barata");
        System.out.println("8. Buscar la carta mas antigua");
        System.out.println("9. Salir");
        System.out.println("*********************************************");

        System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

        opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                String aux = "",
                 aux1 = "",
                 aux2 = "";
                int aux3 = 0,
                 aux4 = 0;
                double aux5 = 0;
                CartaDeRol carta1 = new CartaDeRol();
                System.out.println("nombre de la carta: " + aux);
                aux = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("tipo de carta: " + aux1);
                aux1 = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Descripcion: " + aux2);
                aux2 = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Cuantos dueños a tenido antes? " + aux3);
                aux3 = entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Año de creacion: " + aux4);
                aux4 = entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Precio: " + aux5);
                aux5 = entrada.nextDouble();
                carta1.setNombre(aux);
                carta1.setTipo(aux1);
                carta1.setDescripcion(aux2);
                carta1.setNumDueniosAnt(aux3);
                carta1.setAnioCreacion(aux4);
                carta1.setPrecio(aux5);
                m.addCarta(carta1);

                break;
            case 2:
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es, una vez tienes el método set de cada atributo, introducir en dicho atributo el escaner, para poder leer la información, pero teniendo en cuenta el tipo de atributo.
Por ejemplo, para pedir el nombre sería:

System.out.println("nombre de la carta: "+carta1.setNombre(sn.nextLine));

De esta manera el objeto scanner está leyendo tu entrada, y al mismo tiempo se la está pasando al atributo nombre. Y así haces con los demás.

**Nota:** Recuerda que la clase Scanner también tiene un metodo nextInt(), de esta manera te ahorras el parse y le pasas directamente la entrada a la variable opcion, pero ten presente que después de llamar a dicho metodo, lo mas recomendable es limpiar el buffer, que puedes hacerlo llamando al metodo sn.nextLine(), en una línea aparte.

Comment: Gracias pero ahora tengo otro problema me he dado cuenta deque creaba la carta a pelo y no mediante el método al invocar al metodo ahora me peta los set carta1. Te enseño como lo he echo al final y me dice que te parece.
case 1:  
String aux = "", aux1 = "",aux2 = "";int aux4 = 0; double aux5 = 0;
                    m.addCarta(carta1);
                    System.out.println("nombre de la carta: " + aux);
                    carta1.setNombre(aux);
asi con todos los tributos metiendolos en variables

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes tantas variables aux, y por qué están vacias?

Comment: Pues es la manera que se me ha ocurrido para que me acepte los set antes de leer lo tuyo del scanner. ajajaj. Soy un hombre de recursos :P. la idea es crear una variable vacia hay le doy el valor con el print y luego se la meto al set. No se si me explico

Comment: Casi no, lo mejor sería que me dejaras ver el codigo comopleto donde haces eso

Comment: edito la pregunta para que lo veas. tengo un problema a ejecutarlo y es que al añadir la carta al mazo da error el main (o creo qeu es esa la razon del error) el error es  
xception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at tarea7.Mazo.addCarta(Mazo.java:85)
 at tarea7.GestionDelMazo.main(GestionDelMazo.java:79)
C:\Users\ck\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 33 seconds)

Comment: Y ya inicializaste el mazo de cartas, porque la excepción significa que tu mazo aún no tiene un tamaño establecido

Comment: A ver es que tengo que trabajar con archivos y no se exactamente como funciona entonces tengo los if para crear el archivo si no esta creado y si esta pues serializarlo y pone esto. File miFichero = new File("Coleccion.dat");
        Mazo m = null;
        if (!miFichero.exists()) {
            m = new Mazo();.

Pero no se ese mazo M como darle tamaño o como funciona